# How to copy and paste into another workbook using vba by timer without target workbook popping up each time?

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am copy and pasting data from `workbookA` to `workbookB` every 1 minute interval using the `application.ontime` method. However while I'm running this macro I am working on something different entirely on `workbookC`. Each  time the macro runs, `workbookB` pops up which interferes with what I'm doing on `workbookC`. It can get frustrating... is there a way around this?

My code has the structure:

```
sub dataextract()

ThisWorkbook.Activate 'ThisWorkbook is workbookA

'copy the data

If workbookB Is Nothing Then
    Set workbookB= Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\Df.xlsx")
Else
    Set workbookB= Workbooks("Df.xlsx")
End If

workbookB.Activate 

'paste the data here

workbookB.Save

timer 'timer is the sub that contains the application.ontime loop

end sub
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: this is unlikely to work if you are running a single instance of excel and besides VBA is not a multi-threaded language. if you have excel 2013 it could be easier to run multiple instance of excel, possible allow you to work on wbC while having wbA and wbB running in the background in different xl instance, but below excel 2013 i'm not sure if it can be done. to run a different instance of xl 2013 see here https://blogs.office.com/2013/06/03/opening-workbooks-by-running-separate-instances-of-excel/

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to stop the flashing, using the below function, turn off screen updating (the function includes a few other things too, but don't forget to turn it back on).

```
Sub SetEvents(ByVal State As Boolean)
    With Excel.Application
        .ScreenUpdating = State
        .EnableEvents = State
        If State = True Then .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Else .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub
```

Or stop using the activeworkbook/select range method.  If you define your references properly, ie.

```
Workbooks("Mybook.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").copy
```

The flashing will stop as the workbooks aren't in fact changing.

If you want to include the first option, as per your comment, add the function outside the sub and call it, as below:

```
sub dataextract()
setEvents False
ThisWorkbook.Activate 'ThisWorkbook is workbookA

'copy the data

If workbookB Is Nothing Then
    Set workbookB= Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\Df.xlsx")
Else
    Set workbookB= Workbooks("Df.xlsx")
End If

workbookB.Activate 

'paste the data here

workbookB.Save

timer 'timer is the sub that contains the application.ontime loop
setEvents True
end sub
Sub SetEvents(ByVal State As Boolean)
    With Excel.Application
        .ScreenUpdating = State
        .EnableEvents = State
        If State = True Then .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic Else .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Regarding the first option, where should I put the sub? I inserted it (without a single change) into my module and I don't see any difference...

Comment: As a point in general, if you con't call it, it won't do anything, if you look in the main sub, you pass the true or false parameter to setevents.  Unless you call it with a parameter the sub will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub dataextract()

dim xl as application
dim workbookB as workbook

'ThisWorkbook.Activate 'ThisWorkbook is workbookA, unnecessary to activate workbook when you copy

'copy the data

If workbookB Is Nothing Then
    set xl = new application 'create another excel application
    xl.visible = false        'set the new excel application invisible
    Set workbookB= xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\Df.xlsx")
Else
    Set workbookB= xl.Workbooks("Df.xlsx")
End If

'workbookB.Activate 'unnecessary to activate workbook when you paste

'paste the data here

workbookB.Save

timer 'timer is the sub that contains the application.ontime loop

end sub
```